# Identify C64 Game About Firemen

Tags: commodore-64, identify-this-game

I'm searching for an old game for the C64, it was about a group of firemen. I last played it in the 1989, 32 years ago, so I do not remember it very well.

I remember only that the firemen don't want to get out of bed and you (the game character is a firemen commander/chief) must force them to get out of bed and take the stair to go the firemen truck. Then you go with the truck to help people in an arson.

Games it is **not**:

1. [Fire Game Watch](https://arlagames.itch.io/fire-game-watch-c64)
2. Fireman Sam
3. Shrinking Fireman

Comment: The Incredible Shrinking Fireman?

Comment: No, is not this

Comment: The Moby Games database has few firefighting themed games of that era. FireTrap and Fisher Price Firehouse Rescue, but none have the "wake up sleeping firemen" element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like what you describe -->

Fire-Drill
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb6oUge6UXU

Text from the youtube link:
"Each mission is split into four levels:

1. As the fire chief you must wake your men to get to the exit. Do this quickly or they run back to bed, the cowards!"

Comment: Is this one, thank you very much